# Unable to run classes with a package declaration

Tags: java, package

For some reason, I can't run ANY programs that begin with a package declaration.
Let's say I am trying to run a simple program called 'HelloDate.java'.

```
package Test;
import java.util.*;

public class HelloDate {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, it's: ");
    System.out.println(new Date());

    }
}
```

Both HelloDate.java and HelloDate.class are located in the same folder:

> /Users/eduarddedu/Desktop/Test

I am trying to run HelloDate from inside the 'Test' folder; 'pwd' returns:

> /Users/eduarddedu/Desktop/Test

The `CLASSPATH` variable is not set to anything: `echo $CLASSPATH` returns an empty line.

To my mind, I should now be able to run the program with the command:

> java HelloDate

But all I get is this: `Error: Could not find or load main class HelloDate`

I have also tried setting the `CLASSPATH` to (alternatively) :

> /Users/eduarddedu/Desktop
>
> /Users/eduarddedu/Desktop/Test

Still nothing works.

If I delete the package declaration at the begining, I can run the program just fine, from inside the 'Test' folder or from anywhere else, by setting the `CLASSPATH` variable.

Comment: I think you must run `java HelloDate` in `/Users/eduarddedu/Desktop` instead of `/Users/eduarddedu/Desktop/Test`.

Comment: Try using an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running the file from the wrong directory.

Go to `/Users/eduarddedu/Desktop` and run:

```
javac Test/HelloDate.java
java Test.HelloDate
```

Comment: Eternally grateful! This has been an ordeal.

Answer (score 3):

You should call `java Test.HelloDate` from outside the Test folder.